# google cse button looks tiny

Tags: javascript, search, button, google-api

i'm using google cse in my forum vbulletin it was working fine but when i changed to a new theme (style) the search button of google cse look so small but when i click on it works normaly.
i changed the google cse in different places on the form but still have the same result
so please how to solve this?
code :

```
    <script>
  (function() {
    var cx = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxxxxx';
    var gcse = document.createElement('script');
    gcse.type = 'text/javascript';
    gcse.async = true;
    gcse.src = (document.location.protocol == 'https:' ? 'https:' : 'http:') +
        '//www.google.com/cse/cse.js?cx=' + cx;
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(gcse, s);
  })();
</script>
<gcse:search></gcse:search>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cySBd.png

Answer (score 0):

i found finaly the answer here thanks and it works fine
just i add this css code to my style:

```
 .cse .gsc-search-button input.gsc-search-button-v2, input.gsc-search-button-v2 {
   background-image: inherit;
   box-sizing: content-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
 }
```